# "Expected 1 space after..." message from phpcs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I get this message for a simple line of code where there are no extra spaces as it seems to imply.

I tried disabling and re-enabling phpcs. I tried setting my editor to "spaces: 4" and replacing tabs with such.

The first line is where the "problem" is reported (note the original is indented):

```
if ($timeFromDb == null)
{
```

I was expecting no message, but I got "Expected 1 space after closing parenthesis; found 5".

Comment: same with `{` in same line as `if`? - `if ($timeFromDb == null) {`

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I guess it's not a helpful message.

Comment: which ruleset you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure, a colleague set it up. How can I tell?